# Why can't I re-use a variable name inside of a callback?

Tags: javascript, node.js, scope

I'm trying to re-use a variable named `user` in the following function:

```
UserModel.prototype.authenticate = function (doc, callback) {

    // check to see if the username exists
    this.users.findOne({ username: doc.username }, function (err, user) {

        if (err || !user)
            return callback(new Error('username not found'));

        // hash the given password using salt from database
        crypto.pbkdf2(doc.password, user.salt, 1, 32, function (err, derivedKey) {

            if (err || user.password != derivedKey)
                return callback(new Error('password mismatch'));

            // explicitly define the user object
            var user = {

                _id: user._id,
                type: user.type,
                username: user.username,
                displayname: user.displayname

            };

            return callback(err, user);

        });

    });

};
```

I attempt to redefine the `user` variable inside of the `pbkdf2` callback function. This does not work as I would expect. The lines where I compare `user.password != derivedKey` breaks, because `user` is undefined here during run-time. Shouldn't `user` still be the instance from the `findOne` callback method parameter? If I change either of the two `user` variables to be called something else, it works.

I could just rename the variables, but that would still leave me wondering.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is, you declare a variable called `user` within the function-context:

```
var user = { };
```

This will overwrite / overlap the `user` which was declared as formal parameter by the outer function-context. It does not help to declare that variable after your *if-statement*. Variables declared by `var` and *function declarations* get hoisted up at parse-time, so infact, that `var user` statement is placed just on top of your inner function.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that because of [hoisting](http://www.adequatelygood.com/2010/2/JavaScript-Scoping-and-Hoisting), even though you declare the variable `users` (`var users`) after you use it in other expressions (`user.password != derivedKey`), it gets parsed first, leaving the original `users` reference overwritten.
There are [several docs](http://thecomputersarewinning.com/post/a-dangerous-example-of-javascript-hoisting/) on [hoisting](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/quick-tip-javascript-hoisting-explained/) out there and it may be a good idea to take a peak at them.

Comment: Thank you for the links. This is an important fact to know about Javascript. Glad I now know! :)